# Use QuickText from custom LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, quick-text

Is there any way to invoke the Quick Texts functionality from a Custom LWC?

I know that you can query the QuickText object so you could retrieve and select your records. However if I understand correctly, this wouldn't resolve all the merge fields that the QuickText record could contain in it's message. So I'm wondering if there is any way to use the Quick Text as you would use it from an email or any other compatible object in my LWCs or Aura components.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope everything goes well,

**Clarification on Custom LWC for Quick Messages:**

As I understand, it's possible to create a custom Lightning Web Component for Quick Messages (QM) within another custom LWC. However, to ensure that merge fields function correctly, each merge field must correspond to the record context where the customQuickMessage component is placed. This might involve using a regex or a replace piece of code. By default, if a merge field doesn't have a corresponding context, like when logging a call in a lead that isn't linked to a case but the QM has a merge field like {!case.caseNumber}, it will remain empty.

For instance, consider the usual behavior when clicking on the "Comments" field in a logging a call, where a bubble appears, allowing the selection of a QM. With your custom LWC, you'll need to devise a strategy to achieve similar functionality. This could involve placing a button next to the target field, enabling prepopulation with the selected QM, or exploring techniques to create a bubble-like interaction.

**Verification of Corresponding Channels:**

A field can be checked to verify if a record corresponds to a channel. The "channel" concept indicates whether the Quick Message is available for that type of record or activity, such as phone (call), email, portal, case, etc. (Ref: [QuickText Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_quicktext.htm))

**Security Considerations:**

Remember that Quick Messages can be shared with specific groups by folder. It's essential to ensure that your custom Quick Message component doesn't allow access to Quick Message items where the current user lacks access.

Comment: Thanks. Those are good points. Do you know if it's possible to check if the folder sharing setting is disabled in an org?

Comment: For quick message you can go to Setup > Quick Message Settings > Other Settings section > Share and organize quick text in folders check box. 

After that you need to make sure Folder field is on the layout page for that object, in order to allow users to add QMs to their custom folders.

Comment: Thanks again!! I forgot to specify if it is possible to check it from Apex or a LWC for example

Comment: Mmm not sure for the folder sharing, but if I'm a manager and create a QM only for "Managers" and my apex controller has "with sharing" key, that class will enforce sharing rules of the current user e.g. Sales rep won see that records. I recommend you to test in that scenario. :)

Comment: Sure will do it. Thanks for all the help!!